# grep and find in pipeline. Strange reverse

Tags: regex, bash, grep, pipeline

just find gives me:

```
.
./bla-bla_(11)
./bla-bla_(1)
./rename
./rename~
```

This `find . | grep "*_([0-9]\{1,2\})"` gives me empty result.

and this `find . | grep "([0-9]\{1,2\})_*"` gives me

```
./bla-bla_(11)
./bla-bla_(1)
```

But as you can see underscore and other chars appears before braced digites. Why it works in second case? but not in first where i placed them in right order.

Comment: i think _ is special symbol, it was the reason.

Comment: No, `_` is not special wrt. regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([0-9]\{1,2\})_*
```

matches things like `(11)` or `(1)` followed by *zero or more* underscores.

```
*_([0-9]\{1,2\})
```

matches a `*` followed by `_` followed by something like `(11)`. What you mean is

```
.*_([0-9]\{1,2\})
```

Note the `.`; regular expressions aren't glob patterns.

Comment: `*_([0-9]\{1,2\})` is not a valid regex.

Comment: @kev: actually for `grep` it is. Try `echo '*' | grep '*'`.

Comment: why `echo 'hello' | grep -o 'h**'` print `h`?

Comment: @kev: that's parsed as "zero or more times (zero or more times `h`)", so it should match.

Answer (score 1):

As @kev says, your first regex is invalid: `*` is a quantifier, and it should be preceded by an atom. Here it isn't.

Regexes are not file globs. You probably want `.*`, which means "any character (`.`), zero or more times (`*`)".